# Outlook 2007 - appointment

Tags: outlook, ms-office, outlook-2007, office-2007, appointment

I'm try to set Recurrence Appointment in my caldender for 5th working day on every month.

I can see that i can set the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th and the last day of every month but i cant see option to set for 5th day.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Under 'Recurrence Pattern', select 'Monthly' and put put:

Day [5] of every [1] month(s)

in the bit on the right

-- edit --

Right, looks like this may be of use: http://www.websetters.co.uk/WSAddIns/WSRAII/index.htm

Outlook can't handle that natively as far as I know.

You could do some date crunching in Excel and import them though

Comment: So for e.g. this month February the 5th day is 7th of February 2011.

Comment: I Can do that in excel but i need some like template which i can give to user and they can enter days it will automatically does the full year.

Comment: This is what i have doen.  Date(Every 5th Workday) Subject Start Time EndTime Description Location
Saturday, January, 01, 2011 Majid Test 10:00:00 11:00:00 Test Room 1
Monday, February, 07, 2011     
Tuesday, March, 15, 2011     
Wednesday, April, 20, 2011     
Thursday, May, 26, 2011     
Friday, July, 01, 2011     
Monday, August, 08, 2011     
Tuesday, September, 13, 2011